# How to merge these discontinued branch

Tags: git

I got this weird git tree after changing my laptop, git init seems to fail and I got this discontinued master branch, how can I resolve this ? Thanks

[image]

Here is the git status (sorry) :

```
deleted:    user_guide/license.html
        deleted:    user_guide/objects.inv
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/appflow.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/at_a_glance.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/features.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/getting_started.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/goals.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/index.html
        deleted:    user_guide/overview/mvc.html
        deleted:    user_guide/search.html
        deleted:    user_guide/searchindex.js
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/conclusion.html
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/index.html
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .htpasswd
        .idea/.gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Can you share your `git status`. It looks like you have local changes. Do you wish to save those or not?

Comment: git status :         deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html
        deleted:    user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .htpasswd
        .idea/.gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Yes I wish that my tree include the last changes.

Comment: @Brian85 Please provide any new content as part of the OP, not in comments.

Comment: After you switched laptops, what commands did you call first. Did you do a `git clone`?

Comment: I agree, what does "changing my laptop" mean? What did you do on the new laptop? Where did this repository come from?

Comment: This repo was on my precedent laptop.

Comment: I think I've made a git init... it was a mistake

Comment: @Brian85 did you ever call `git clone` on the new laptop? Running `git init` on an existing repo is safe. I would go out on a limb and assume that you have created a directory and in that directory ran `git init` instead of `git clone`. Did you setup any remotes after that?

Comment: I just copied my files on the new laptop and made a git init and here is the result after a commit. I dont have a git clone. How can I clean this ? A rebase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear to me how you got into this state, but it *appears* as though when you copied the repository, this copied *most* of the files but omitted two very important files:

- It somehow left out the `HEAD` setting and/or `refs/heads/master` reference (probably the file `.git/refs/heads/master`), and
- it somehow left out the index file (`.git/index`).

The "6273 changed" is also alarming, especially given that `git status` shows only about 18 things changed (but perhaps you've trimmed it and there are many more `deleted` files, which would make more sense and match my guess that  `.git/index` got removed and since then re-created with very little in it).

Since then, you managed to create a new `master` branch that is unrelated to your existing `origin/master` remote-tracking name.  If this were my own laptop ... well, I probably would not be in this state at all :-) but I might start by *renaming* the existing `master` branch:

```
git branch -m master save
```

I might also commit again just to make sure that `save` has the current status saved (so that it has 2 commits instead of just 1, and `git status` stops listing anything except perhaps a few untracked files).

Then, I'd create `master` from `origin/master` using:

```
git checkout -t origin/master
```

or:

```
git switch -t origin/master
```

or—to use the "DWIM mode" that creates a branch from its `origin/` counterpart—just:

```
git checkout master
```

or:

```
git switch master
```

If this works well and everything seems to be recovered, you can leave the `save` branch around until you are comfortable with the situation, then delete the `save` branch.

Other options include retrying the copying of the repository, this time making sure that the index and current branch get copied properly; or, if there's a good copy somewhere—such as on GitHub—that allows cloning, just clone the good copy as a fresh clone.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations.